# How to uninstall ProxyChains in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, uninstall, proxychains

I mess few things while editing proxychain4 file. Then I searched in online, one answered mentioned that use apt-get purge proxchain4. I did that afterwards when tried to reinstall Proxychain4 it is not happening. moreover when I use - locate proxychain4 - I'm still able to see . why? it is appearing. Then I deleted the contents of that file.  What should I do now?

Comment: The `locate` command is run from a database that's only updated about once a day unless you use `updatedb` to do it manually. This can cause newly created files/directories/links to not be found and those that are deleted to still appear. Kali Linux is for experienced users so if you can't figure out what to do, it's not the distro for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt purge proxychains
```

On kali the package name is [`proxychains`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/proxychains).

On debian the package [`proxychains`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/proxychains) is also provided by [`proxychains4`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/proxychains4)